# Как передать в функцию void izmena переменную из main

Tags: c++

Как передать в функцию void izmena переменную из main

```
// Описание структуры процесса
struct Process {
    int pid; // идентификатор процесса
    int pc; // счетчик команд
    int state; // состояние процесса (0 - неактивен, 1 - активен)
};

// Описание основного класса модели ОС

class OSModel {

    
public:


int memSize; // размер памяти
    int freeMem; // свободная память
    int speed; // скорость моделирования в тактах в секунду
    int activePid; // идентификатор активного процесса
    vector<Process> processes; // таблица процессов
    
    

    // Конструктор класса
    OSModel(int memSize);

    // Процедура инициализации модели
    void init();

    // Процедура генерации нового задания
    void generateTask();

    // Функция проверки наличия свободной памяти
    bool checkFreeMem(int size);

    // Процедура загрузки нового задания
    void loadTask(int pid, int size);

    // Процедура выполнения очередного такта активного процесса
    void executeNextTick();

    // Процедура выполнения программной задержки
    void delay();

    // Процедура индикации параметров
    void showParams();
    
    void vivod();
    void OSModel::izmena(){

     for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
    Process process = processes[i];
    if(process.state==0){
        process.state=1;
       cout << process.pid << "\t" << process.pc << "\t\t" << process.state << endl;

    }
i++;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понятно, то ли ты хочешь, но вот:

```
void OSModel::izmena(const int value)
```

`int` замени на свой тип и `const` можешь убрать если не надо.

Main:

```
int main() {
    OSModel osModel;
    int var;
    osModel.izmena(var);
    return 0;
}
```